# Get text to change in the link when toggle is activated

Tags: jquery

Hi all I would like to change the text from **Hide information** to **Show information**

when toggling the top link of the accordion I am making.

Also at the bottom of the accordion there is a link inside the element I am slide toggling, when this link is clicked I would like to change the text on the top link only and hide this one as it is currently doing.

here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
//On Click
$('.collapseLink').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next(".revealBoxContents").stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
});

$('.collapseLink').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.revealBoxContents').stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

});

and here is the URL

http://satbulsara.com/NSJ-local/eqs1.htm

Thanks,

Sat

Answer (score 0):

How about using a callback function? With the selector element :visible you can detect what the current state of your slide element is and display the corresponding text.

Something like this:

`$('.collapseLink').click(function(){ 
   $(this).parent().next(".revealBoxContents").stop(true, true)
   .slideToggle('slow', function(){
         var txt = ($('#yourelement').is(':visible')) ? 'hide' : 'show';
         $('#togglelink').html(txt);
   })
});`

...how to format the code?

Comment: After the slidetoggle function is executed it will end up in the specified callback function. In that function we look at the current state of the sliding element. If it is visible, we set the text of the link to 'hide' and otherwise we set it to 'show'.